Windows 11 - lock screen keeps reverting from slideshow to picture
Note: I am asking this question so that I can post the answer straight away and hopefully help someone in the future
I have an app which is setting the Windows lock screen to display a slideshow. I do this by setting registry values
I have found that every so often, the lock screen slideshow stops working, and when I open the lock screen settings, it is showing "picture" instead of "slideshow"
When the lock screen slideshow is not working, the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lock Screen\SlideshowEnabled value is still set to 1, but as soon as I open the settings screen, that registry value reverts to 0

After many many days of trying to track down why the lock screen kept reverting from slideshow to picture, I found that it was happening as soon as I set a registry key relating to the screensaver
To be specific, it was when I set a value in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\SCRNSAVE.EXE registry value, but I have also found that it happens if I do something like change the screensaver timeout value using the windows dialog
So when you make any changes relating to the screensaver, it reverts the lock screen from slideshow to picture. Why does this happen? I don't know
Hopefully this saves someone a whole lot of time in the future, as I couldn't find any mention of this Windows quirk when I was doing my troubleshooting

UPDATE: We have also found that if you have a screensaver set, and then you change the lock screen from picture to slideshow, that the screensaver gets reset to None
Is seems that making this change to the lock screen removes the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\SCRNSAVE.EXE registry key
